# SQLite force close when opening database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have one button that calculates and saves the percent increase in a baby's height and weight, and another button for saving name and birthday.

But my code causes a force close...

My Database Java:

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //Table name
    public static final String TABLE_BABY = "Baby_table";
    //Table columns
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_BIRTH_DATE = "birth_date";
    public static final String COLUMN_INITIAL_HEIGHT = "initail_height";
    public static final String COLUMN_INITIAL_WEIGHT = "initail_weight";

    //Table name
    public static final String TABLE_MEASUREMENTS = "Measurements_table";
    //Table columns
    public static final String COLUMN_HEIGHT = "_height";
    public static final String COLUMN_WEIGHT = "_weight";
    public static final String COLUMN_NUM = "_num";
    public static final String COLUMN_BABY_NAME = "_Babyname";  

    //Database file name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Baby.db";
    //path
     private static String DB_PATH = "";

    //Database version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    static final String viewBaby ="ViewBaby";

    //Constructor
    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

       /** DB_PATH = "/data/data/"
                + context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                + "/databases/"; */
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {




         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEASUREMENTS + "("
                   + COLUMN_NUM+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_HEIGHT + "Integer," +COLUMN_WEIGHT+ "Integer,"+COLUMN_BABY_NAME+"TEXT NOT NULL ,FOREIGN KEY ("+ COLUMN_BABY_NAME +") REFERENCES "+TABLE_BABY+" ("+ COLUMN_NAME +"));");

           db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_BABY + "(" +COLUMN_NAME +"TEXT PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_INITIAL_HEIGHT +" Integer," + COLUMN_INITIAL_WEIGHT+"Integer,"+COLUMN_BIRTH_DATE +"DATE)");


        //db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
      db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER fk_babyname_measurmentname1" +
                " BEFORE INSERT "+
                " ON "+TABLE_MEASUREMENTS+

                " FOR EACH ROW BEGIN"+
                " SELECT CASE WHEN ((SELECT "+ COLUMN_NAME +" FROM "+TABLE_BABY+
              " WHERE "+COLUMN_NAME+"=new."+COLUMN_BABY_NAME+" ) IS NULL)"+
                " THEN RAISE (ABORT,'Foreign Key Violation') END;"+
                "  END;");

     // Create view
      db.execSQL("CREATE VIEW "+viewBaby+
            " AS SELECT "+TABLE_MEASUREMENTS+"."+COLUMN_NUM+" AS _id,"+
            " "+TABLE_MEASUREMENTS+"."+COLUMN_HEIGHT+","+
            " "+TABLE_MEASUREMENTS+"."+COLUMN_WEIGHT+","+
            " FROM "+TABLE_MEASUREMENTS+" JOIN "+TABLE_BABY+
            " ON "+TABLE_MEASUREMENTS+"."+COLUMN_BABY_NAME+" ="+TABLE_BABY+"."+COLUMN_NAME
            );

    }




    /** Called when the DATABASE_VERSION is changed to higher version */
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_BABY + TABLE_MEASUREMENTS);

          db.execSQL("DROP VIEW IF EXISTS "+viewBaby);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //insert 




/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
/**
 * @return
 */
public long getLastInsertId() {
     long index = 0;
        SQLiteDatabase sdb = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sdb.query(
                "sqlite_sequence",
                new String[]{"seq"},
                "name = ?",
                new String[]{MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_MEASUREMENTS},
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            index = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("seq"));
        }
        cursor.close();
        return index;
}



public void insertWeightAndHeight(String column, Long value) {
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(column, value);
   db.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_MEASUREMENTS, null,
          initialValues);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void open() throws SQLException {
    // void
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    //return dbHelper;
}
/** Used to close connection with database. */
public void close() {
    //if(database != null)
    //{database.close();}

    this.close();
}




public void insertDate(Date birthdate) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SQLiteDatabase database=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    /**Used to parse from Date to String and the other way around*/
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    initialValues.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_BIRTH_DATE, dateFormat.format(birthdate));
    database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_BABY, null,
        initialValues);
}
public void insertName(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase database=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NAME, name);
    database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_BABY, null,
        initialValues);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

/** used to get Last height & weight from TABLE_MEASUREMENTS by Num.*/

 @SuppressWarnings("null")
 public static Long getLastHeight(){
     @SuppressWarnings("unused")
     SQLiteDatabase database=dpHelper.getWritableDatabase();
     Cursor cursor = null;
     int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_HEIGHT);
    Measurements measurement = new Measurements();
    MySQLiteHelper sqlliteHelper = null ;
    Long i= sqlliteHelper.getLastInsertId();
     String[] asColumnsToReturn = new String[] { COLUMN_HEIGHT};
     cursor = database.query(TABLE_MEASUREMENTS,asColumnsToReturn, "COLUMN_NUM = i",null,null,null,null );
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Long height = cursor.getLong(index);
    return height;
 }

/** used to get Last h  n eight & weight from TABLE_MEASUREMENTS by Num.*/

 @SuppressWarnings({ "null", "unused" })
public static Long getLastWeight(){
     SQLiteDatabase database=dpHelper.getWritableDatabase();

     Measurements measurement = new Measurements();
     Cursor cursor = null;
     int index =cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_WEIGHT);
    MySQLiteHelper sqlliteHelper = null ;
    Long i= sqlliteHelper.getLastInsertId();  
     String[] asColumnsToReturn = new String[] { COLUMN_WEIGHT};
      cursor = database.query(TABLE_MEASUREMENTS,asColumnsToReturn, "COLUMN_NUM = i",null,null,null,null );
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    Long weight = cursor.getLong(index);
    return weight;
 }


/** used to get Last h  n eight & weight from TABLE_MEASUREMENTS by Num.*/
 static MySQLiteHelper dpHelper;


 public int caluclateAge() throws ParseException{
     SQLiteDatabase database=dpHelper.getWritableDatabase(); 
     String[] asColumnsToReturn = new String[] { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_BIRTH_DATE};
     Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_BABY,asColumnsToReturn, null,null,null,null,null );
     /**Used to parse from Date to String and the other way around*/
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
     Date  Birthdate = dateFormat.parse(cursor.getString(3));
     Calendar dob = Calendar.getInstance();
        dob.setTime(Birthdate);
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
     int age = today.get(Calendar.MONTH) - dob.get(Calendar.MONTH);

      return age;

 }

 }
```

Chart Activity:

```
public class ChartActivity extends Activity {
    //private BabyAdapter adapter;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(this);

        final WebView googleChartView = new WebView(this);
        db.open();

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final EditText EditText3 =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            final EditText EditText4 =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4); 
                //BabyDataSource BDS = new BDS();
            Long h =MySQLiteHelper.getLastHeight();
            Long W =MySQLiteHelper.getLastWeight();
            String h2;
            String w2;
            Long oneH ;
            Long twoH ;
            Long threeH ;
            Long oneW ;
            Long twoW ;
            Long threeW ;
            Long hPercent;
            Long wPercent;
            Long HV;
            Long WV;

            if (h == null && W == null){
                hPercent =(long) 0.0 ;
                wPercent =(long) 0.0;
                h = (long)0.0;
                W = (long)0.0;
                h2 = EditText3.getText().toString();
                w2 = EditText4.getText().toString();
                HV = Long.parseLong(h2);
                WV = Long.parseLong(w2);
                db.insertWeightAndHeight(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_HEIGHT, HV);
                db.insertWeightAndHeight(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_WEIGHT, WV);
            } else {
                h2 = EditText3.getText().toString();
                w2 = EditText4.getText().toString();
                HV = Long.parseLong(h2);
                WV = Long.parseLong(w2);
                oneH = HV-h;
                twoH = oneH/h;
                threeH = twoH *100;
                hPercent = threeH ;
                oneW = WV-W;
                twoW = oneW/W;
                threeW = twoW *100;
                wPercent = threeW ;

                db.insertWeightAndHeight(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_HEIGHT, HV);
                db.insertWeightAndHeight(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_WEIGHT, WV);
            }

            String strH = hPercent.toString();
            String strW = wPercent.toString();
            EditText3.setText(strH +"%");
            EditText4.setText(strW +"%");
            //chart
            setContentView(googleChartView);
            String mUrl = "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chf=bg,s,245245245&chxs=0,FFFFFF00,9.5&chxt=x,y&chxl=0:Xheight|currentHeight|Xweight|currentWeight&chs=500x300&cht=bvg&chco=3072F3|FF9900|80C65A|990066&chd=t:"+h+","+HV+","+W+","+WV+"&chdl=50%%20X-Height|5%%20Current-Height|5%%20X-Weight|40%%20Current-Weight&chdlp=b&&chbh=10,5,5";
            googleChartView.loadUrl(mUrl);

            db.close();
            // Perform action on click
        }
       });

       final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
       button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
               final  EditText EditText1;
               final  EditText EditText2;

               EditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
               EditText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

               SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
               String  BirthDateStr = EditText2.getText().toString();

               String name = EditText1.getText().toString();         
               Date Birthdate;
               try {
                   Birthdate = dateFormat.parse(BirthDateStr);
                   int age = db.caluclateAge();
                   db.insertDate(Birthdate);
                   db.insertName(name);
                   EditText2.setText("your "+name+" is now "+age+"month old");
               } catch (ParseException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       });
    }
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        //Close dataSource
    }
}
```

This is the logcat:

```
05-14 12:23:43.095: I/Process(224): Sending signal. PID: 224 SIG: 9
05-14 12:28:10.824: D/dalvikvm(305): GC freed 555 objects / 48344 bytes in 92ms
05-14 12:28:11.424: E/Database(305): Failure 1 (near "TABLEBaby_table": syntax error) on 0x2d5de0 when preparing 'CREATE TABLEBaby_table(_nameTEXT PRIMARY KEY,birth_dateDATE)'.
05-14 12:28:11.434: D/AndroidRuntime(305): Shutting down VM
05-14 12:28:11.434: W/dalvikvm(305): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
05-14 12:28:11.434: E/AndroidRuntime(305): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-14 12:28:11.454: E/AndroidRuntime(305): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{chart.android.project/chart.android.project.ChartActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEBaby_table": syntax error: CREATE TABLEBaby_table(_nameTEXT PRIMARY KEY,birth_dateDATE)
05-14 12:28:11.454: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
05-14 12:28:11.454: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
05-14 12:28:11.454: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
05-14 12:28:11.454: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
05-14 12:28:11.454: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-14 12:28:11.454: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-14 12:28:11.454: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-14 12:28:11.454: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 12:28:11.454: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-14 12:28:11.454: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-14 12:28:11.454: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-14 12:28:11.454: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-14 12:28:11.454: E/AndroidRuntime(305): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEBaby_table": syntax error: CREATE TABLEBaby_table(_nameTEXT PRIMARY KEY,birth_dateDATE)
05-14 12:28:11.454: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
05-14 12:28:11.454: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1610)
05-14 12:28:11.454: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at chart.android.project.MySQLiteHelper.onCreate(MySQLiteHelper.java:69)
05-14 12:28:11.454: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
05-14 12:28:11.454: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at chart.android.project.MySQLiteHelper.open(MySQLiteHelper.java:193)
05-14 12:28:11.454: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at chart.android.project.ChartActivity.onCreate(ChartActivity.java:34)
05-14 12:28:11.454: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-14 12:28:11.454: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
05-14 12:28:11.454: E/AndroidRuntime(305):  ... 11 more
05-14 12:28:11.474: I/dalvikvm(305): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
05-14 12:28:11.474: E/dalvikvm(305): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

the new logcat

```
    05-15 20:27:47.319: W/dalvikvm(341): Exception Ljava/lang/NullPointerException; thrown during Lchart/android/project/MySQLiteHelper;.<clinit>
05-15 20:27:47.329: D/AndroidRuntime(341): Shutting down VM
05-15 20:27:47.339: W/dalvikvm(341): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
05-15 20:27:47.339: E/AndroidRuntime(341): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
05-15 20:27:47.409: E/AndroidRuntime(341): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
05-15 20:27:47.409: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at chart.android.project.ChartActivity.<init>(ChartActivity.java:27)
05-15 20:27:47.409: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-15 20:27:47.409: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1479)
05-15 20:27:47.409: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
05-15 20:27:47.409: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
05-15 20:27:47.409: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
05-15 20:27:47.409: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
05-15 20:27:47.409: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
05-15 20:27:47.409: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-15 20:27:47.409: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-15 20:27:47.409: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
05-15 20:27:47.409: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 20:27:47.409: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-15 20:27:47.409: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
05-15 20:27:47.409: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
05-15 20:27:47.409: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-15 20:27:47.409: E/AndroidRuntime(341): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-15 20:27:47.409: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at chart.android.project.MySQLiteHelper.<clinit>(MySQLiteHelper.java:46)
05-15 20:27:47.409: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  ... 16 more
05-15 20:27:47.429: I/dalvikvm(341): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
05-15 20:27:47.429: E/dalvikvm(341): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to debug for you. Can you narrow the problem down to a representative sample?

Comment: Oh, and might I recommend using a more standard indentation style? IDEs are great at automatically reformatting code, and it helps readability a lot.

Comment: the problem in sqlite thats why i put database code and where i use it in activity. when i use any method in database the application force colse

Answer (score 1):

This line from your logcat:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEBaby_table": syntax error: CREATE TABLEBaby_table(_nameTEXT PRIMARY KEY,birth_dateDATE)
```

Tells us that you have at least one syntax error when you create `TABLE_BABY`:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_BABY + "(" +COLUMN_NAME +"TEXT PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_INITIAL_HEIGHT +" Integer," + COLUMN_INITIAL_WEIGHT+"Integer,"+COLUMN_BIRTH_DATE +"DATE)");
  // Need a space here  ^  and another one over here        ^  ...
```

It should be:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_BABY + "(" + 
    COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " + 
    COLUMN_INITIAL_HEIGHT + " INTEGER, " + 
    COLUMN_INITIAL_WEIGHT + " INTEGER, " + 
    COLUMN_BIRTH_DATE + " DATE)");
```

Make sure you add the right spaces in your SQL statements.

This is true for all of your tables, here is `TABLE_MEASUREMENTS` for example:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEASUREMENTS + "(" +
    COLUMN_NUM + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
    COLUMN_HEIGHT + " INTEGER, " + 
    COLUMN_WEIGHT + " INTEGER, " + 
    COLUMN_BABY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
    "FOREIGN KEY ("+ COLUMN_BABY_NAME +") REFERENCES " + TABLE_BABY + " (" + COLUMN_NAME +"))");
```

Try to use a format that is easy for you to read, that will help prevent these mistakes.  Have fun!

**ADDITION**

You stated that the Null Pointer Exception is "in line 46 the path", do you mean this?

```
   /** DB_PATH = "/data/data/"
            + context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
            + "/databases/"; */
```

I'll assume that this is the line with the error (and that you didn't tell us that you are using this line).

This line could be simplified as:

```
DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
```

But this is the best way:

```
DB_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
```

Comment: a post the new log cat in my question ..@Sam

Comment: What's on line 46 in the constructor of MySQLiteHelper? `(05-15 20:27:47.409: E/AndroidRuntime(341): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-15 20:27:47.409: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at chart.android.project.MySQLiteHelper.<clinit>(MySQLiteHelper.java:46)`